# Input/output impedance of devices in a circuit simulator

Tags: circuit-analysis, simulation, impedance, proteus, multisim

I have to use a circuit simulator (I'm using Proteus, but can also use Multisim if necessary), to construct and analyse a passive RC filter. The general circuit is shown below:

[image: RC circuit]

I need to connect this circuit to a function generator with source impedance \$R_\mathrm{S}\$, and an oscilloscope with load impedance \$R_\mathrm{L}\$, so I've placed the signal generator in the place of \$V_\mathrm{in}\$ and the oscilloscope in place of \$V_\mathrm{out}\$.

Now I have to find the values of the impedances \$R_\mathrm{S}\$ and \$R_\mathrm{L}\$. As this is being done on a circuit simulator, I'm assuming that both impedances will be 'ideal' at 0\$\Omega\$ (or ∞\$\Omega\$, I'm not sure). Can anyone confirm if I'm right in saying this, and if not, how would I go about finding \$R_\mathrm{S}\$ and \$R_\mathrm{L}\$?

Answer (score 1):

In esence I thing that your assumption is right. However, I recommend you to attach a current source and calculate the thevenin equivalent that will give you the impedance of the system. With that you can check your simulation.

Answer (score 0):

the tool Signal Chain Explorer has an explicit top-level mode(main menu) for Zin and Zout of stages.

The download and use is free. From "robustcircuitdesign.com".

Note the tool models a chain of stages ( a chain ) and does not allow a general graph.

Comment: I downloaded the tool and had a quick play around. I constructed my circuit using the default V based sensor stage, with a value of 1kΩ for R, and 16nF for C (aiming for a cutoff frequency of 10kHz). When I click Zin or Zout it produces a graph with 4 different plots (Z, R, X and I). Am I right in saying that the values I'm looking for would be found at the point where the Z plot meets a frequency of 10kHz?